# Storm Local Cluster works but StormSubmitter fails

Tags: apache-storm

I have two topology. One of which is very simple, Spout generates a random number and the Bolt saves the same in the database. This topology works fine both as a local cluster and when submitted to Storm using `StormSubmitter`.

The next one, though is little complicated, follows the same code pattern as the previous topology. This topology, works perfectly when implemented as `LocalCluster` but doesn't work when I use `StormSubmitter`. What could be the reason this fails?

I don’t get any errors, but I see this in the log file

```
2015-07-16T11:24:59.376+0530 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] Reconnect started for Netty-Client-/192.168.1.117:6700... [1]
838 2015-07-16T11:25:09.532+0530 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] Reconnect started for Netty-Client-/192.168.1.117:6700... [2]
839 2015-07-16T11:25:19.702+0530 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] Reconnect started for Netty-Client-/192.168.1.117:6700... [3]
840 2015-07-16T11:25:29.837+0530 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] Reconnect started for Netty-Client-/192.168.1.117:6700... [4]
841 2015-07-16T11:25:40.010+0530 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] Reconnect started for Netty-Client-/192.168.1.117:6700... [5]
842 2015-07-16T11:25:50.187+0530 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] Reconnect started for Netty-Client-/192.168.1.117:6700... [6]
843 2015-07-16T11:26:00.442+0530 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] Reconnect started for Netty-Client-/192.168.1.117:6700... [7]
844 2015-07-16T11:26:10.760+0530 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] Reconnect started for Netty-Client-/192.168.1.117:6700... [8]
845 2015-07-16T11:26:21.174+0530 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] Reconnect started for Netty-Client-/192.168.1.117:6700... [9]
```

Even when I check Storm UI, the topology is successfully running, but none of the local logs are printed. None of the DB operations are executed. But everything are executed as expected with LocalCluster.

**EDIT**

storm.yaml:

```
 storm.zookeeper.servers:
   - "127.0.0.1"
 storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
 nimbus.host: "127.0.0.1"
 storm.local.dir: "/tmp/storm-data"
 java.library.path: "/usr/local/lib"
 storm.messaging.transport: backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Context
 supervisor.slots.ports:
      - 6700
      - 6701
      - 6702
      - 6703
```

Comment: This question is too general. What causes the topology to fail? Is there any error in the log?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, Added an edit.

Comment: There is obviously a network connection problem (can you `ssh` from each machine to all others without passphrase?) In which log file to you see this messages? Nimbus? Supervisor? Worker?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, I am just testing this locally. I am running a local Storm nimbus and Supervisor. And this is from the worker log file.

Comment: It seems that the worker cannot connect to the supervisor. I guess `192.168.1.117` is your local IP (I am wondering why it is not showing `localhost`) ? What is your `storm.yaml` configuration?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, Added storm.yaml

Comment: I am wondering, why there is `192.168.1.117` in the log and not `localhost` (is localhost equal to 192.168.1.117?). Can you ssh to localhost wihtout passphrase? Btw: Why so you not just use `LocalCluster` for local setup?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, `192.168.1.117` is my ip address, just checked thru ifconfig. I am fine with `LocalCluster` but my problem is `StormSubmitter` works for my other topology but I don't see any process happening for this topology.

Comment: I have no clue so far. How many spouts/bolts do both topologies have? What is the configured dop for each spout/bolt in in both cases? Did you try to `ssh localhost` without passphrase  (just to make sure it works -- this will be necessary such that workers can communicate with each other)